# defining a tikz pic within a style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm trying to understand how to deal with namespaces in tikz. This is a reasonable thing to want to understand and is self-evidently on topic for TeX.SE. Also the question clearly contains enough details for anyone to understand what it's asking.

The short version of this question is: if I define a pic inside a style it renders differently from if I define it outside the style. (In particular, the label doesn't show.) I would like to understand why this is.

The reason I want to know is that I'm trying to define a fairly complicated set of tikz macros for drawing diagrams of a particular kind, and it made sense to me to try and put everything inside a single style, to avoid putting it all in the global namespace. But I'm not sure if this is really what I should be trying to do - I'm finding it hard to get a sense of how tikz "thinks" about namespaces and what the intended best practices are for this sort of thing, so any advice on that would also be helpful.

Below I give two MWE's. The first one works as expected, and defines a pic that looks like this:

[image]

The second one is my attempt to put the pic inside a namespace by defining it inside a custom style. It parses correctly but the label doesn't show:

[image]

The main point of the question is to understand why this happens.

First the working version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset {
    pics/my pic/.style = {
        code = {
            \node at (0,0) [pic actions, shape=rectangle] {#1};
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw pic[draw] {my pic=$f$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then the version that tries to put the pic in a style but doesn't work as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset {
    my style/.style = {
        pics/my pic/.style = {
            code = {
                \node at (0,0) [pic actions, shape=rectangle] {#1};
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my style]
    \draw pic[draw] {my pic=$f$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: a `pic` is not a `style`

Comment: @BlackMild this is true. In my second MWE there is both a pic and a style, which are indeed different things. The pic is defined inside the style. The question is about why this behaves in the way demonstrated, with the pic being drawn but not its label.

Comment: @Nathanial a `style` is a set of graphic options. In fact, `style`s is used as a shorthand to shorten code. A `pic` is a set of graphic commands; it is a (small) picture. They are totally different. So defining a `style` as a `pic` is not intended, not standard, and may cause some unexpected behavior.

Comment: I know they are different. I'm not defining a style as a pic - I don't even know what it would mean to do that - I'm defining a pic inside a style. Probably you are right that this is not the correct or expected thing to do, but I would still like to understand what's going on, because I'd like to understand how tikz works in more detail than I currently do.

Comment: Or perhaps you're referring to the part of my code where it says `tikz/my pic/.style = {...`? That part is completely standard tikz, straight from the manual. The part I'm asking about is in my second example, where I nest that inside `my style/.style = {...`.

Comment: In my opinion, it is wrong way of using `style` when defining a pic inside a style. You can check pgfmanual,pdf, section 12.4.2

Comment: That section describes only the very basics of using styles and does not mention pics.

Comment: I do not see anything similar or meant to `myS/.style ={pics/my pic/.style = {...}} in the pgfmanual
`